# Amazon SES Error for VERIFIED address "MessageRejected: Email address is not verified"

Tags: amazon-ses

I have an Amazon SES connection setup which is currently in Sandbox mode.

I have my email address, I use my real one but for this post let's call it `myemail@arealdomain.com`. It's verified in SES, in the email tab it says "verified" right next to it.

I have a Node app which sends the mail via Nodemailer

```
this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  SES: new aws.SES({ region: "us-east-1" })
});

this.defaultFromAddress = 'myemail@arealdomain.com';
```

and then I send it with this.transporter.sendMail, with ALL email addresses being the same `myemail@arealdomain.com`

When I try to send an email, (both TO and FROM the same address, which is Verified on SES)

On send I get the below error

```
Error: MessageRejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: myemail@arealdomain.com
```

Any ideas how to fix?

**update**

Per the conversation below I triple confirmed both my region and email address is correct across both my code and AWS. The to and from address are the same, and is listed in AWS as "verified". I'm still having this issue and totally unsure how to proceed

**update2**

Sending a "Test Email" from the SES dashboard works just fine, using the same email addresses...

**update3**

It gets weirder! So we got out of Sandbox mode yesterday and are a normal SES account now. Same exact errors no matter what combo of to/from addresses I'm using. I'm always using a "verified" address as the FROM, and no matter the TO (even if it's also a verified address) I get the exact same error that

> Error: MessageRejected: Email address is not verified. The following
>   identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1:
>   myemail@arealdomain.com

Comment: *in the email tab it says "verified" right next to it.* ...but in the top right corner of the screen, does it say N. Virginia? Or does it say Oregon?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Good question but yes it also says N. Virginia, so everything is us-east-1 :-\

Comment: I really thought I had you there.  You're absolutely sure there's no typo anywhere that the address is being used?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I quadruple checked by copying the "verified" one from aws into my clipboard, and then ctrl+f to accurately find it in both the to and from address in my code

Comment: Somewhere in the back of my mind, I remember a bug where SES would complain about address X when the problem was really the lack of an address field in the MIME headers of the message.  Can you create and show an MCVE that both builds and sends a simple message, that reproduces this behavior in a sandbox environment?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I just tried again with a brand new (and verified) address. Same result. I'm not sure how to create an MCVE as it's in node and uses aws and nodemailer. For what it's worth, I'm using *identical* code in another application that's life and working as expected

Comment: Is the casing identical?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, the casing is identical, also see my update to my question... it gets weirder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so it turns out while I was running locally it was using the incorrect AWS credentials (for an other project). Still unsure how to fix but that's the actual problem nothing wrong with SES

Comment: I too had the same issue. Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem today, and after checking all the credentials and the SES dashboard, the answer turned out to be a case-sensitivity issue in the left-hand side of the address.  The verified email was:

noreply@company.com

but I was setting

NoReply@company.com

in the header, and that caused the verification to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue today. Wasted couple of hours on this.

SESv2Client library for node.js uses the default aws-cli config when the credentials config is not passed propery.

```
const ses = new SESv2Client({ 
    region: 'region-code',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'ABC',
        secretAccessKey: 'xyz'
    }
});
```